# Mouse Click removing active class on certain questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form of questions, most just YES or NO type responses. I have all the questions working and the YES NO toggle working on them as well. For some reason though when I get to question 3 and pick a choice it will add the active class to that button, but if I click anywhere else on the screen, it removed that active class. Not sure why it's doing this. Question 3 is also the first question with a sub question that appears if the user selects YES.

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 study-question" id="q-2">
                <p><strong>2.</strong> HAVE YOU HAD SHINGLES?</p>
                <input name="radio" type='hidden' value="Yes"/>
                <div class="btn-group btn-toggle">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default yes-no btn-1" data-radio-name="radio">Yes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default yes-no" data-radio-name="radio">No</button>
                </div>
            </div>

           <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 study-question" id="q-3">
                <p><strong>3.</strong> HAVE YOU HAD PAIN IN THE AREA OF THE SHINGLES RASH FOR AT LEAST THE LAST 3 MONTHS?</p>
                <input name="radio" type='hidden' value="Yes"/>
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default yes-no" data-radio-name="radio" value="yes">Yes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default yes-no" data-radio-name="radio" value="no">No</button>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 study-question sub-question">
                            <p><strong>3A.</strong> IF IT HAS NOT YET BEEN 3 MONTHS, HOW LONG WOULD YOU ESTIMATE THIS PAIN HAS BEEN ONGOING?</p>
                            <input name="radio" type='hidden' value="Yes"/>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control study-form-control" id="how-many-year" placeholder="How long?">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
    $('.yes-no').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('div').find('.yes-no').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    $(this).addClass('active');


    $(this).val()=='yes'?$(this).closest('div').find('.sub-question').show():$(this).closest('div').find('.sub-question').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML - you forgot to add the class `btn-toggle` to the DIV parent of the second buttons group:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/fudomu/1/edit)***

jQuery:

```
$('.yes-no').click(function(){

  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('div').find('.sub-question').toggle(this.value==='yes');

});
```

Comment: Thanks...I think it's time to call it a day ;)